# How to read and write using core data on ios 8 swift?

Tags: iphone, swift, core-data, ios8, xcode6

So, in xcode6 I am making an app for iphone that can record sports times and allows you to view your past times in a table view and graphs etc. The problem is that i am having trouble using the core-data.

On my first screen I have a text box for a title and time, and then a button to enter your time. What I want to do is when you hit the enter button it will take the time and title and store them into a file to be read later. My question here is "how do you save data in swift using core-data?"

On the second screen I have a simple table view that I want to read the stored data and display it. My question here is "How do you read the stored data?"

PS: Is core-data what I am looking for?

Comment: "PS: Is core-data what I am looking for?" I sure don't think so. What were you thinking it would do for you?

Comment: I thought core data was something to store data @matt

Comment: Mmmmm, no. Here's my take on it, for what it's worth: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch36.html#_core_data

Comment: As far as I can tell from your question all you need is some variables. You don't need to save or read anything.

Comment: @matt, variables do not save if you close the app

Comment: I know that. Did you even look at the chapter of my book I referred you to?

Comment: thanks for referring me to that book @matt